# How to only change the background color of the output color cells in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using the `chesterish` Jupyter NoteBook theme

```
jt -t chesterish -fs 95 -tfs 11 -f office -nfs 12 -nf loraserif -lineh 190 -cellw 65% -T -N -kl
```

I like the theme, but I woundlike to change the background color of the code output cells...

How to only change the background color of the output color cells in Jupyter Notebook?